# SAQL sort without including field in the return results

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, einstein

I need to sort by a field in a SAQL query, but I do not want that field to appear in my results.

For example, I am trying to do this

```
q = load "xxx";
q = foreach q generate 'account_id' as 'account_id', 'asset_type' as 'Asset Type', 'asset_name' as 'Asset Name', 'asset_link' as 'Asset Link';
q = order q by ('rank' asc, 'Asset Type' asc);
```

but I get the following error.

> Unknown IDTOKEN: rank

However, if do this:

```
q = load "xxx";
q = foreach q generate 'account_id' as 'account_id', 'asset_type' as 'Asset Type', 'asset_name' as 'Asset Name', 'asset_link' as 'Asset Link', 'rank' as 'rank';
q = order q by ('rank' asc, 'Asset Type' asc);
```

It works just fine.

I don't want the `rank` field to appear on my results, but I do not seem to have any luck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending another query line should work here:

```
s = foreach q generate 'account_id' as 'account_id', 'asset_type' as 'Asset Type', 'asset_name' as 'Asset Name', 'asset_link' as 'Asset Link'
```

So the final `SAQL` would become

```
q = load "xxx";
q = foreach q generate 'account_id' as 'account_id', 'asset_type' as 'Asset Type', 'asset_name' as 'Asset Name', 'asset_link' as 'Asset Link', 'rank' as 'rank';
q = order q by ('rank' asc, 'Asset Type' asc);
s = foreach q generate 'account_id' as 'account_id', 'asset_type' as 'Asset Type', 'asset_name' as 'Asset Name', 'asset_link' as 'Asset Link'
```

> **Explanation:** Here the variable 'q' has got the resultset sorted. Now in variable 's', I am selecting the required fields from the resultset
>   'q'

Hope this helps!